# jQuery mobile not resizing after page change

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a phonegap app using jquery mobile among other things and previously found a solution browsing StackOverflow that works fine on the initial page and orientation changes.

My issue comes after moving from one page to another. It seems to resize, but does it too much, I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to fix this?

```
function contentHeight() {
'use strict';
var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight(),
    header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight(),
    footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight(),
    contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height(),
    content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;

/* Apply calculation */
$(".ui-content").height(content);
}
```

This is the function I found submitted somewhere on here.

```
$(window).bind('load resize orientationchange', contentHeight);
$(document).ready(contentHeight);
$(document).on('throttledresize orientationchange pagecontainertransition', contentHeight);
```

And these are the events I'm hooking into.

As mentioned, when you first load the main initial web-page it works as intended, but clicking a link to another web-document adds that extra 50-80px height at the bottom.

I'll attach the CSS and 2 of HTML files that I'm working with so anyone can see for themselves.

[HTML File #1](http://hastebin.com/ozokuqaruy.html)

[HTML File #2](http://hastebin.com/avakenujaf.html)

Thanks in advance for any help or insight!

Comment: CSS File:  http://hastebin.com/zokaleceji.css

Comment: have you registered your function on second html page too? If not then you will need to register it on second page to work. But creating two separate html files for JQM apps is not a good practice.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the function itself should be global.I tried adding a console.log() elements to the function to see what's going on and it's adding 76 pixels to subsequent pages regardless if you're using a multi-page single HTML layout or using multiple HTMLs.

Comment: is your same function is working when next page loads?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Yes, the function is loading fine with the new page, the only difference from the first "initial" page is that it adds an extra 70-80 pixels to the maximum height of the content DIV for some reason. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing around, what I finally ended up doing was adding:

```
target-densityDpi=device-dpi
```

to the meta viewport tag, then:

```
data-position="fixed"
data-id="myID"
data-tap-toggle="false"
```

to the footer itself. That solved all scaling issues (even while changing orientation) as well as fixing the footer jumping up when you tapped any kind of focus elements such as a select menu.